# How inject MvcJsonOptions in AspNet Core 1.1?

Tags: asp.net-core

I cannot use static `JsonConvert` settings, and in my filter I need to format string according to current `MvcJsonOptions`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(x =>
{
    x.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});

class ReturnBadRequestForInvalidModelFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        private readonly MvcJsonOptions _options;

        public ReturnBadRequestForInvalidModelFilter(MvcJsonOptions options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        ...

        private string FormatPropertyName(string key)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                return key;

            return _options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver is CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
                ? char.ToLowerInvariant(key[0]) + key.Substring(1)
                : key;
        }
```

Comment: Does that not work? Does it error? It's not quite clear what your question is, sorry.

Comment: It is failed, `MvcJsonOptions` is not a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by [JsonResultExecutor.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json/Internal/JsonResultExecutor.cs) try using `IOptions<MvcJsonOptions>`:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public MvcJsonOptions JsonOptions { get; set; }

    public YourClass(IOptions<MvcJsonOptions> mvcJsonOptions)
    {
        JsonOptions = mvcJsonOptions.Value;
    }
}
```